# Cobalt 10.49488 can not render "http://qual-e.appspot.com"

Tags: cobalt

we checkout the latest version **Import Cobalt 10.49488** and built it.
Cobalt still not render qual-e page.
Did this version  support http://qual-e.appspot.com or we still need to wait next ?

***Test command:***

```
./cobalt --allow_http --csp_mode=disable --url=http://qual-e.appspot.com/?enableLogs=1
```

Comment: Bug reports and questions about schedules should go to the project mailing list. In this case: cobalt-dev@googlegroups.com

Comment: Note that there is already a bug for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35339754

Answer (score 1):

qual-e.appspot.com has been updated and the main pages should work properly now.
I just confirmed with Cobalt 10.49488, its able to render the Home and Conformance pages.

Not all sub-pages have been updated, see the issuetracker referenced by David Ghandehari above.

Answer (score 0):

migrate to **Cobalt 11.62465**. If you need to use the stable release, use `9.62469` from `RELEASE_9` **branch**.

Update on the progressive tests:
If you use up-to-date Cobalt version, I expect you can pass all the progressive tests.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35339754) they will re-open to examine.

Comment: fyi, release_11 is a latest stable release version.